# Problemas Login Python Selenium, Urllib, Urllib2, request!

Tags: python, python-2.7, login, selenium, mechanize

Quiero loguearme a esta pagina: `https://onevideo.aol.com/#/` y he probado con request, selenium, urllib2, urllib, mechanize... y no he podido ni siquiera poder encontrar el xpath del username y el boton de submit. Mejor dicho si los encuentro pero no puedo acceder a ellos, una vez que los copio me dice que no puede encontrar los elementos. Seria ideal poder hacerlo con selenium en python 2.7 que es lo que mas trabajo. Les dejo mi loguin con la contraseña para poder probarlo.

Cabe destacar que no habia tenido problemas de este tipo con ninguna web que necesitara login

Con cualquier libreria que pueda lograrse ya es un gran paso para mi. Gracias

```
Email: martinmartin998
Password: bMtpzXGrRb39
```

Comment: Hola Martin, ¿como es que lo estás haciendo?, ¿puedes mostrar tu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que observamos es que el `id` del input ("onevideo_login_username") o su nombre ("adaptv_email") no van a ser validos para seleccionarlo porque hay dos elementos en el html con la misma id y nombre (uno deshabilitado y otro es el que queremos). Lo mismo pasa con el botón.  Una posible soluciona es usar el selector css.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es establecer unos tiempos de espera adecuados para que la pagina cargue completamente en un principio y entre ambos pasos del login. Lo suyo es esperar a que estén disponibles los inputs.

Usando como driver Gecko (Firefox) puedo loguearme sin ningún problema con el siguiente código

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/")
timeout = 30

try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)")
username.send_keys("martinmartin998")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(2)").click()

try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")
password.send_keys("bMtpzXGrRb39")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button").click()
driver.close()
```

Script en funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo ni siquiera puedo loguearme usando el explorador. Lo intenté usando las credenciales pero me redirige nuevamente al login.

Comment: @César pues que raro, acabo de probar de nuevo el script y se loguea sin problemas (he añadido un gif del proceso). Despues de cerrar sesión he probado también con el navegador (Firefox) y tampoco tengo problemas.

Comment: Ah, ni modo. Debe ser un tema de mi Chromium :-p

Comment: Excelente amigo mío, pero como hiciste para encontrar el css??

Comment: @MartinBouhier como he comentado uso Firefox, desconozco el mejor camino en otros navegadores. Lo que suelo hacer es  abriendo el `Inspector` (Ctrl + Mayus + c ) basta con ir al `Input` o al elemento que se quiera, click derecho en el código html de ese elemento en el inspector, `Copiar`, `Selector css`. Con esto se copia en el portapapeles el selector css de ese elemento y lo pegas en el script tal cual. No se el navegador que usas pero supongo que no deberías tener problemas para hacer algo similar.

Comment: Si puedes chequear la ultima pregunta que hice me vendria muy bien, estuve utilizando el Selector css y pude moverme por toda la UI sin problemas. Necesito un poco de ayuda con unas cosas! Gracias @FJSevilla